# get and display api response from php file and display in android activity using retrofit in java

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I want to display the response that I got from PHP code.
My PHP code is:

```
if ($query) {
    $response['message'] = "Saved";
    $response['error'] = false;
} else {
    $response['message'] = "Not Saved";
    $response['error'] = true;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

I want to display the message and error on activity

My java code is:

```
Call<String> call = updateInterface.updateData(getId, studentData[0], studentData[1], studentData[2]);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                        editPrg.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable throwable) {

                        //hide dialog
                        editPrg.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error updating record", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
```

I want to display PHP response in onResponse() method. Kindly guide me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a response class. For example, ServiceResponse. Your class should be like this:

```
class ServiceResponse{

    private String message;
    private Boolean error;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Boolean getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Then, your Retrofit call should be like this:

```
Call<ServiceResponse> call = updateInterface.updateData(getId, studentData[0], studentData[1], studentData[2]);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ServiceResponse>() {...}
```

With that code you will be able to show your response in your activity.

So, in resume, you have always to create a response class according with what your service response to you.